# How Can I replace IF by Selectors with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the feeling I'm doing dirty code, although it works fine...

How could I replace those IF statement by regular JQuery selectors in such case:

see code + fiddler

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="#b" class="cssPauseAll" historyID="12">Pause All</a><br/>

        <a href="#b" itemHistoryID="12" ContentID="45">AA</a><br/>
        <a href="#b" itemHistoryID="12" ContentID="14">BB</a><br/>
        <a href="#b" itemHistoryID="12" ContentID="78">AA</a><br/>  

    <a href="#b" class="cssPauseAll" historyID="13">Pause All</a><br/>

        <a href="#b" itemHistoryID="13" ContentID="45">BB</a><br/>
        <a href="#b" itemHistoryID="13" ContentID="14">BB</a><br/>
        <a href="#b" itemHistoryID="13" ContentID="78">CC</a><br/> 
</body>    
</html>​
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("click","a.cssPauseAll[historyID]", function () {
        var historyID = $(this).attr("historyID");
        //alert("historyID from PauseAll  " + $(this).attr("historyID"));
        $(document).find("[itemHistoryID]").each(function() {

            var itemHistoryID = $(this).attr("itemHistoryID");

            if(historyID == itemHistoryID)
            {
                alert($(this).attr("ContentID"));
            }
        });

    });

});​
```

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/kzFze/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the strings:

```
$("a[itemHistoryID='" + historyID + "']");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FBCBP/

Please note that there is no need to select the document object and use the `find` method. You can select the element using `$` or `jQuery` directly and also using attribute selector alone is very slow, you can use element selector before attribute selector(*in this case*`a`).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you should be able to do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on("click","a.cssPauseAll[historyID]", function () {
    var historyID = $(this).attr("historyID");
    //alert("historyID from PauseAll  " + $(this).attr("historyID"));

    $(document).find("[itemHistoryID='" + historyID + "']").each(function() {
        // here only the matching itemHistoryIds will loop
        alert($(this).attr("ContentID"));
    });

});

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is exactly this way, you can use `nextUntil` instead of `each` loop thrue all elements, you know that only the next `a` elements have `itemHistoryID` equals to the clicked link.

```
$(document).on("click","a.cssPauseAll[historyID]", function () {
    var historyID = $(this).attr("historyID");

    $(this).nextUntil('a[itemHistoryID!="' + historyID + '"]', 'a').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('ContentID'));
    });

});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqgcP/)